# Number of unacknowledged messages in RabbitMQ queue

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I want to obtain number of unacknowledged messages in RabbitMQ queue.

How can I achieve it?

I tried to use [HTTP API](https://rawcdn.githack.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/v3.8.8/priv/www/api/index.html), concretely `/api/queues/vhost/name`, but it always returns 0 `messages_unacknowledged` and `messages`

Comment: How do you make sure the `messages_unacknowledged` is not 0, have you enabled management plugin

Comment: I run rabbitmq management docker image which has management plugin enabled by default, i.e. HTTP API is exposed

Comment: So you access to management web page found `messages_unacknowledged` not 0?

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP (REST) API (management plugin) is not real time; it lags reality.

Comment: Do you happen to know what to use instead?

Comment: I am not aware of anything; I suggest you try the rabbitmq-users Google group.

Comment: I found `org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin#getQueueProperties`. Is it also laggy?

Comment: No; that is real time since it runs over the AMQP connection; however, it only has a consumer and message count (it doesn't break down the message state).

Comment: `assert rabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(queueName).get(QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT) == 0` in a loop does the trick

Comment: I interpreted your question to mean you wanted a count of unack'd (Vs. ready) messages.

Comment: After some experimentation, it can happen `rabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(queueName).get(org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT)` returns 0, even though messages are being processed.. `QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT` doesn't include unacked messages.

Comment: Per your question in rabbitmq-users, if you just want to check that the listener processed `n` messages, you can use the `RabbitListenerTestHarness` - [docs here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.2.11.RELEASE/reference/html/#test-harness).

Answer (score 0):

`rabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(queueName).get(org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT)` does the job

`RabbitAdmin` is a bean which is automatically configured by Spring Boot.